# Prove that there exist infinitely many triples $(a,b,c)$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $P(x)=x^2+2016x+1$. Prove that there exist infinitely many triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c$ are distinct and $Q(P(a))=Q(P(b))=Q(P(c))$ where $Q(r)$ is the greatest prime divisor of $r$.

We see that $P(x+P(x))=P(x) P(x+1)$. How do we continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

The range of $P$ is $[w,\infty)$ for some $w \in \mathbb R$. (it is easy to calculate $w$, actually)

Now let $p$ be a prime number greater than $3$ and greater than $w$. (observe that there are infinitely many such primes)

Since $p \in [w, \infty)$ (the range of $P$), there is a number $a$ such that $P(a)=p$. So, $Q(P(a))=Q(p)=p$.

Also, $2p \in [w,\infty)$ and so, there is a number $b$ such that $P(b)=2p$. Of course, $Q(P(b))=Q(2p)=p$ holds.

Finally, $3p \in [w,\infty)$ and thus there is $c$ such that $P(c)=3p$. We have $Q(P(c))=Q(3p)=p$.

Comment: This looks correct, why did it get down-voted?

Comment: I guess the OP is asking for integer values, otherwise any divergent function would do the job.